# Wireless ad-hoc network not visible

Tags: windows-xp, ad-hoc-network

I am attempting to share my Windows XP workstation's LAN connect with my OS X laptop via wifi, using the Samsung wireless 'dongle' that came with my Samsung TV (wis09abgn).

I followed [CNet's instructions](http://cnettv.cnet.com/make-your-laptop-hot-spot/9742-1_53-28619.html) to create an ad-hoc network.

While the ad-hoc network appears to have been created, I can't 'see' it from either my OS X laptop or from my Android telephone.

The 'cnet' network added to the wireless-network properties panel:

[image]

The properties of the 'cnet' network:

[image]

Advanced properties set to 'ad hoc' network:

[image]

Changed LAN settings to allow network users to connect:

[image]

The 'cnet', ad-hoc network as listed in the workstation's wireless networks:
[image: wireless networks]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought an [Airlink WiFi adapter](https://web.archive.org/web/20111012145516/http://www.airlink101.com/products/awll5099.php) and everything worked as expected.

I had to use its software, rather than allowing Windows to configure the WiFi network, however.

Answer (score 1):

Just create an ad-hoc connection to the network you've set up from your client. It may not be visible for some reason, but it is still available. This worked for me; I just told the client device to connect to an ad hoc network of the correct SSID and security credentials and voilá!

This should at least work for client laptops, not sure about Android.